# The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

m new in c#.m working on C# and .net.I  am stuck with this prob for two month.when i deleting row from gridview it gives error The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.

```
try
{
          if (dgvLetterSent.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
          {
              BindingManagerBase bm = dgvLetterSent.BindingContext[dgvLetterSent.DataSource, dgvLetterSent.DataMember];
              DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)bm.Current).Row;    

              if (dr[7].ToString() != "Not Specified")
              {
                  MessageBox.Show("Cannot remove the letter once it has been printed.", "NPB Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
              }
              else
              {
                  dtInviteLetter.Rows.Remove(dr);//this give me exception that The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection.
                  dtInviteLetter.AcceptChanges();
                  fetchPaymentDetails();
               }
          }
}
catch { }
```

Comment: dr comes from dgvLetterSent (a DataGridView I guess), and therefore is not in dtInviteLetter (a DataTable probably), unless dgvLetterSent is bound to dtInviteLetter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both datarows come from different sources? So it's normal that you're getting this error.

You can only remove rows from `dtInviteLetter` that are members of the `DataRowCollection` of `dtInviteLetter`.